# json_encode returning null for UTF-8 charset

Tags: php, json

I have a json file like this

```
{"downloads":[
    {
        "url":"arquivo1.pdf",
        "descricao":"árquivo 1"
    },
    {
        "url":"arquivo2.pdf",
        "descricao":"arquivo 2"
    }
]}
```

And I save it using **UTF-8 encode** via **Notepad++**.

Then I get the file content:

```
function getContent($name)
{
    $content = file_get_contents("configs/" . $name . ".json");
    $encoded = utf8_encode($content);
    return json_decode($encoded);
}
```

and `json_decode` returns `null`.

If I save the json file as ANSI then it works. But I'd like to save it as UTF-8.

Comment: if the file is already in utf-8 you don't have to re-encode it a second time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that the initial file is either already in UTF-8 or in a badly formatted type.

> **NULL** is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

**Bad encoding**

You can check if your input content is already valid utf-8 by doing this:

```
$is_valid_utf8 = mb_check_encoding($content, 'utf-8'));
```

If it is, don't re-encode it.

The documentation has more to offer: http://php.net/mb-check-encoding

**BOM**

Or maybe Notepad++ sets a BOM which could confuse `json_decode`.

```
//Remove UTF-8 BOM if present, json_decode() does not like it.
if(substr($content, 0, 3) == pack("CCC", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF)) {
    $content = substr($content, 3);
}
```

see [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#112631)'s documentation.

Comment: Notepad++ has an option to enconde Without BOM. Now I'm using that. Before i was using the short option. thats why it didn't work indeed. thank you. I dont know what is this BOM for.

Answer (score 0):

json_decode woks fine with UTF-8 without BOM. Do you have any particular reason to use BOM?

If you convert your json file to UTF-8 without BOM you will not need to encode the content later with utf8_encode.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because your file is already in UT8, and when you encode it again using `utf8_encode()`, PHP assumes your string is an ISO-8859-1 string and therefore breaks it.